# How to Block a range of IP address with UFW

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I am trying to block a range of IP address on my Ubuntu 16.04LTS server from a specific country, i.e. China, Iran, etc.

I was hoping to find a script or something I could run to easily make a dynamically updating list. As in I just put in country codes and it auto populates the current list from somewhere then appended my block range. Making it easy to updates for the list of address as they change. But to start with I used [country ip blocks](https://www.countryipblocks.net/country_selection.php)
to find a list of addresses for China and saved them to a text file titled "chinaiprange.txt"

After some searching I found the following command to enter them all in at once from [this](https://scottlinux.com/2013/08/30/block-geo-region-list-of-ips-with-ufw-in-linux/) example

`while read line; do sudo ufw insert 1 deny from $line to any; done < chinaiprange.txt`

However when I run it I recieve the following output:`ERROR: Bad source address`

The addresses are saved in the following format:

```
1.0.1.0/24 
1.0.2.0/23
1.0.8.0/21
...
```

If there is a better way to do this that would be great but letting me know what I am doing wrong would be just as awesome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the `chinaiprange.txt` file was not saved with Windows-style line (CR-LF) endings?

Comment: @steeldriver I am not sure... When I open the file in nano it does say "converted from DOS format". Is this what you are referring to? If so how do I change it?

Comment: That does indeed indicate Windows (DOS) line endings: you can convert the file using `dos2unix`, or by opening it in `vi` instead of `nano` and then executing `:set ff=unix` followed by `:wq` to re-save, or for example using `sed -i 's/\r$//' chinaiprange.txt`. After that, I expect your original command should work.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you! That appears to be working for me now! It will probably take awhile to run but I will close this out once I can confirm the rules have been added.

Comment: The solution was to change the file format. A big thanks to @steeldriver for finding the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-read `man ufw`. There are two, similar, `ufw` invocations that you're confusing:

```
   ufw [--dry-run] [delete] [insert NUM] allow|deny|reject|limit [in|out] [log|log-all] PORT[/PROTOCOL]

   ufw [--dry-run] [rule] [delete] [insert NUM] allow|deny|reject|limit [in|out [on INTERFACE]] [log|log-all] [proto PROTOCOL] [from ADDRESS [port PORT]] [to ADDRESS [port PORT]]
```

You probably want to

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny on eth0 from $line
```

Comment: I tried that and now I get the following message
'ERROR: Invalid token 'on''

Comment: AFAIK he nested usage syntax `[foo|bar [baz]]` indicates that `baz` is an optional parameter of `foo` or `bar`. So in this case `deny in` or `deny out` (implying all interfaces) or `deny in on eth0`, `deny out on eth0` (a specific interface) are legal - but `deny on eth0` without specifying one of `in` or `out` are not

Comment: I have tried the change of adding "in" to the command but it now gives me the same "bad address error" I am thinking @steeldriver is correct in that I have the wrong file format for it to be read. I created the text file on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the syntax of your command (either of the `ufw` command itself, or the bash loop - although it would be good practice to quote the `$line` variable i.e. `... from "$line" to any ...`).

The `ERROR: Bad source address` error indicates a problem with the address string itself, and we can guess that it might be due to DOS-style `CR-LF` line endings - which you were able to confirm by opening the `chinaiprange.txt` file in `nano`

The solution is to fix the line endings, using any of the well known methods such as:

- running your file through the `dos2unix` command
- using `tr` or `sed` - for example `sed -i 's/\r$//' chinaiprange.txt`
- opening the file in `vi` and executing `:set ff=unix` followed by `:wq` to re-save